# Git merge two totally different branches

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

I start a project and so far so good.
Happens that after some months i start a refactoring , removing duplicated code and renamed methods and so on. So far so good, but this branch was unstable.
Then due to bug fixes i made changes to old code that i must integrate in the refactoring branch.
The problem is that code changed in these 2 branches and its really a lot of code.
ex: `branch refatoring` has no code duplicates and of course new methods.
`branch master` contains all the bug fixes in the old code after `refatoring`.
What is the best strategy?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The best way would be to cherry-pick your commits on the new branch and see if you get conflicts. Also you might need to look at the code commit and see whether you need to change any syntax or pattern to make it compatible for a new code. 

I went ahead with the above strategy on my Refactor work and it worked great instead of taking a pull from the original branch